# Total number of paths on a 2 x 7 grid

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> An ant must visit each vertex of a 2 x 7 grid exactly
> ONCE. The ant starts in the bottom left corner and must end its
> journey in the top right corner. The ant can only travel to its
> immediate left, right, front or behind. How many different paths can
> the ant take?

[GRID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXa6D.png)

I've figured out that there are 23 total steps that the ant must take.

In a previous question, where the ant could only travel up or rightwards, I used 9!/(7!)(2!). However, I can't figure out how to apply the same principle to this question...

I know I'm looking for the total number of Hamiltonian paths, but I'm not sure if a formula exists for calculating the total number of such paths.

This question is also from a high school book that does not cover network theory, so I'm guessing there is a method to solve this that does not require understanding of Hamiltonian paths...

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXa6D.png]

Answer (score 1):

Let's get some intuition of how ant's paths look like.

## Example 1

Consider an example path ant might take. Let's say it goes `→ → → ↑`:

```
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   B
                             
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
            ↑                
A → . → . → .   .   .   .   .
```

How should it continue its journey from this point? If you think about it, the ant has only one choice for its next 8 steps:

```
. → . → . → . → .   .   .   B
↑                            
. ← . ← . ← .   .   .   .   .
            ↑                
A → . → . → .   .   .   .   .
```

From this point the problem of finding the remainder of the path is very similar to the original problem, except point `A'` is on the top, and grid is smaller:

```
                A'  .   .   B
                             
                .   .   .   .
                             
                .   .   .   .
```

## Example 2

Let's start again from the point `A`, assume ant goes right all the way till the 6th column:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   B
                             
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
                             
A → . → . → . → . → . → .   .
```

How should ant continue its journey from here? Take a moment to convince yourself, that there's actually only one possible continuation:

```
. → . → . → . → . → . → . → B
↑                            
. ← . ← . ← . ← . ← . ← . ← .
                            ↑
A → . → . → . → . → . → . → .
```

## Example 3

Similarly, let's start from the point `A'`, and also assume ant goes right all the way till the 6th column:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
                A'→ . → .   B
                             
                .   .   .   .
                             
                .   .   .   .
```

How should ant continue its journey from here? Convince yourself, that there's only one possible continuation:

```
                A'→ . → .   B
                        ↓   ↑
                . ← . ← .   .
                ↓           ↑
                . → . → . → .
```

## Observations

1. The 6th column is special: once ant reaches 6th column for the first time, it has only one choice for the remainder of its path.
2. Each time ant reaches column $k \in \{0, 1, ... 5\}$ for the first time, it is faced with two choices:

   A) Go `→`, in which case it directly proceeds to column $(k + 1)$

   B) Go vertically (`↑` or `↓`), in which case for its following actions it has only one choice, until it reaches column $(k+1)$.

## Conclusion

Each time ant reaches column $k \in \{0, 1, ... 5\}$ for the first time, it has two choices, in all other cases it has exactly one choice. Hence the total number of paths is $2^6$.